How to define grammar for minimum 1 of foo and maximum 1 of bar
In parsimonious, I'm trying to define a grammar where there has to be one occurrence of foo and zero to 1 occurrence of bar and in any order.
How do I get parsimonious to throw an error ?
from parsimonious.grammar import Grammar

g = Grammar(r"""
    text = ws* "section" ws* (foo / bar)+ ws*  
    foo = ws* "foo" ws*
    bar = ws* "bar" ws*
    ws = ~"\s*"
""")

print(g.parse("""section foo""")) 
print(g.parse("""section foo bar bar"""))  # How to throw error as more than one bar
print(g.parse("""section bar""")) # How to throw error as foo is required
print(g.parse("""section bar foo"""))  
print(g.parse("""section foo bar"""))  


Probably easier to just enumerate the possibilities, foo, foo bar, or bar foo. (Or should that be "at least one" occurrence of foo, matching the title?)

Your grammar isn't correct.
You are looking for
text = ws* "section" ws* foo*  bar foo* ws*  

